# What is wrong with my Beautiful Soup find_all code here?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I feel like I'm missing something really basic, but I'm stuck. I'm trying just to return a single table with Beautiful Soup, but for some reason it's not grabbing the table with the line score by ID. I can target other divs and tables by their ID on this page just fine, but for some reason this one isn't returning anything. Any idea what I'm missing?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/2020-01-14-19-clemson.html'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
ls = soup.find_all('table', {"id": "line-score"})
```

[Web inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HybLr.png)

Comment: it seems the problem is with calling that id

Comment: ive tried it for a bit and ive confused myself aswell

Comment: i suggest using requests package, that helped me

Answer (score 0):

That table appears to be added by javascript, if you actually view the source (right-click view source instead of inspect) you will see the table is commented out in html.
You would need to render the actual page in a browser and get the generated source.

Answer (score 0):

As Ipellis said, the table you are trying to scrape is added by Javascript.That means that the table is being rendered after you make the initial request, therefore the HTML code doesn't contain it.

To get the data from it, I suggest you to switch from `BeautifulSoup` to `requests-html` (a very similar library). This one handles these Javascript cases and also handles the web request.

You will need to install it first: `pip install requests-html`.

Then, you simply do this:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
request = session.get('https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/2020-01-14-19-clemson.html')
request.html.render() # Here is where you render the table

table = request.html.xpath('//table[@id="line-score"]')
```

I suggest you using `xpath` when looking for your elements. It is a much better way of getting to the elements you are looking for. If you don't understand xpaths, here is the [Xpath tutorial by W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).

You can get the documentation of `requests-html` [here](https://github.com/psf/requests-html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the table is added through JS, but the data is already in the source code. You can get it in the following way

```
from simplified_scrapy.request import req 
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html = req.get('https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/2020-01-14-19-clemson.html')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
table = doc.getElement('table',attr='id',value='line-score')
trs = table.trs.notContains('thead',attr='class').notContains('colspan') # Filter out the head
for tr in trs:
  tds = tr.children
  print ([td.text for td in tds])

table = doc.getElement('table',attr='id',value='four-factors')
trs = table.trs.notContains('thead',attr='class').notContains('colspan') # Filter out the head
for tr in trs:
  tds = tr.children
  print ([td.text for td in tds])
```

Result:

```
['Duke', '33', '39', '72']
['Clemson', '40', '39', '79']
['Duke', '73.5', '.574', '19.3', '13.8', '.185', '98.6']
['Clemson', '73.5', '.642', '19.3', '20.7', '.208', '108.2']
```

You can get the examples of SimplifiedDoc [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the table by rendering. The following code uses the pyppeter library.

```
from simplified_html.request_render import RequestRender
req = RequestRender({ 'executablePath': '/Applications/chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'})
def callback(html,url,data):
  from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
  doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
  table = doc.getElementByID('line-score')
  trs = table.trs.notContains('thead',attr='class').notContains('colspan') # Filter out the head
  for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.children
    print ([td.text for td in tds])
req.get('https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/2020-01-14-19-clemson.html',callback)
```

Result:

```
['Duke', '33', '39', '72']
['Clemson', '40', '39', '79']
```